# Text get truncated when assigned to datarow cell in datatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, dataset, interop

I am trying to convert excel to `dataset` for some processing. I am using following code:

```
private DataSet ConvertExcelToDataset(string path, string sheetName)
{
    Excel.Application oExcel = null;
    Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
    Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    Excel.Range range = null;

    try
    {
        oExcel = new Excel.Application();
        workbooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
        workbook = workbooks.Open(path);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            //If passed sheetName is "All" then reading all sheets
            //If passed sheetName is not "All" then reading only sheet whose name is passed
            if (sheetName != "All" && sheet.Name != sheetName)
            {
                continue;
            }

            range = sheet.UsedRange;

            int rows = range.Rows.Count;
            int cols = range.Columns.Count;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(sheet.Name);
            int noofrow = 1;

            //If 1st Row Contains unique Headers for datatable include this part else remove it                    
            for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
            {
                string colname = sheet.Cells[1, c].Text;
                dt.Columns.Add(colname);
                noofrow = 2;
            }

            for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
                {
                    dr[c - 1] = sheet.Cells[r, c].Text;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            //clean up  
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
        }

        //Closing workbook
        workbook.Close();
        //Closing excel application
        oExcel.Quit();

        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex);

        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        //clean up           
        if (range != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        if (workbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        if (workbooks != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
        if (oExcel != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);
    }
}
```

It works fine but if suppose any cell in row in excel file contains big string which contains more than 30,000 characters, it gets truncated. After debugging I found issue in following line

```
dr[c - 1] = sheet.Cells[r, c].Text;
```

So how can I avoid this string truncation?

Comment: Is it definitely 30000 characters, Excel has a limit of 32767 characters in a cell.

Comment: So maybe the limit comes from Excel itself. 30k chars is like 8 A4 pages with char size 11, I don't know why anyone would have to store 8 A4 pages in an Excel cell

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there any way to avoid this truncate?

Comment: The 32,767 characters per cell  is a limitation of Excel that cannot be changed. If you are trying to store more than that in a cell in Excel, then it will be truncated - it is not an issue with your code.

Comment: It is indeed a limitation of Excel (see [specs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)). As the "truncate" is happening in Excel, you certainly cannot avoid it in C#. [This article](https://excel.tips.net/T003163_Character_Limits_for_Cells.html) suggests some not-so-pretty workarounds such as using text boxes.